# SDL2 rendering only on winforms panel

Tags: .net, winforms, c++-cli, sdl-2

I want to use SDL2 in my C++/CLI .NET winforms application.
I want to render a texture on my winforms panel and not want to create another SDL window form just for rendering. How can I do that?

Comment: SDL_CreateWindowFrom(), [example](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/124804/sdl2-in-a-vs2015-c-panel)